# Create a padded image in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, sobel

I have a grayscale image (called input) and I'm trying to add 1px padding (made up of 0 only) around the image in order to apply a filter:

```
padded = np.zeros((input.shape[0]+2, input.shape[1]+2), dtype=int)
padded[1:-1, 1:-1] = input[:,:]
```

but the result is less contrasted than the original. Why?
This is the original image:

[image: link]

and this is the bordered image:

[image: link]

If instead of using the zeros function I use the once function and multiply the matrix by 255, I get an even different image. I don't understand why as I just copy one image into another.

Comment: Are you making those images with `plt.imshow` or . . . ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`plt.imshow` docs:](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)

> **X** : array-like or PIL image
>
> The image data. Supported array shapes are:
>
> - (M, N): an image with scalar data. The values are mapped to colors using ***normalization*** and a colormap. . . .

Normalization means that the colors are "spread out" so that the minimum is black and max is white.  So those `np.zeros` are making the minimum `0` (and the border black) and making everything else lighter to compensate.  This should work to fix it (I think)

```
padded = np.pad(input, 
                pad_width = 1, 
                mode = 'minimum') # or mode = "maximum' for a white border
```

If you absolutely need a border of `0`, you can do:

```
padded = np.pad(input - input.min(), 
                pad_width = 1, 
                mode = 'constant')
```

That changes the range of your original picture to start a `0`, so the normalization should be the same.

Comment: In this case i use pylab.imshow. The problem is that I need a border made of 0 to apply a Sobel filter. Using np.pad I add a padding with values grater than 0 and then the calculations are not performed correctly.

Comment: check my edit, you can also move to image data so the minimum is `0` so that you keep the edges `0` while the normalization should keep the same range.

Comment: Eventually I found out that what I needed was mode = 'edge'. Thank you so much for letting me discover this function!